# Integer solutions of $13x − 7y = 1?$

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Number theory is largely concerned with properties of
the set of positive integers, and as such has a considerable
overlap with algebra. But a simple example that
illustrates the difference between a typical question in
algebra and a typical question in number theory is provided
by the equation
$$13x − 7y = 1.$$

- An algebraist
  would simply note that there is a one-parameter family
  of solutions: if $y = λ$ then $x = (1 + 7λ)/13,$ so the
  general solution is $(x,y) = ((1 + 7λ)/13, λ).$
- A number
  theorist would be interested in integer solutions,
  and would therefore work out for which integers $λ$ the
  number $1 + 7λ$ is a multiple of $13.$ The answer is that
  $1 + 7λ$ is a multiple of $13$ if and only if $λ$ has the form
  $13m+ 11$ for some integer $m.$

How do we get the solution $13m + 11?$

(I have tried understanding this again and again. But where I seem to lose track is how do you jump from k= 11 to k = 13j + 11  )

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: I guess that the above question is mostly a citation from some book. It would be a nice thing to say which one. As for the _actual_ question (the last sentence), please reformat the question to make sure it is clear that _that_ is what you want to know.

Comment: Its from princetons companion of mathematics.

Comment: two parts:   describe all $13u - 7 v = 0.$   Find two $(x,y)$ solutions to $13x - 7 y = 1.$  Take the difference of the two solutions   and compare to the  $(u,v)$ pairs, which make what we call a lattice.

Comment: You can see why $1+7\lambda$ must be divisible by $13.$ So, we are looking for $\lambda$ such that $1+7\lambda=13k$ for some integer $k.$ Now, you know that each integer is of the form $13m+r$ for some $0≤r≤12.$ So, there are $13$ cases to consider for $\lambda.$ Considering them gives the solution $\lambda=13m+11.$ Alternatively, one can use modular arithmetic to arrive at $7\lambda \equiv_{13} 12.$ The inverse of $7$ in $\mathbb{Z}/13\mathbb{Z}$ is $2.$ This gives $\lambda\equiv_{13} 11.$

Comment: $$13x-7y=1\iff13(x+1)=7(y+2)$$$$\iff x=7k-1,y=13k-2$$$$\iff x=7m+6,y=13m+11$$ for some integers $k=m+1.$

Comment: $\!\bmod 13\!:\ -7y \equiv 1 \iff y \equiv \dfrac{-1}7 \equiv \dfrac{-2}{14}\equiv \dfrac{-2}1\equiv 11\,$ by *Gauss's algorithm*. See the linked dupes for this and many other methods methods.

Comment: 1*13+0*7=13, 0*13+1*7=7. Subtract(2) from (1) and 1*13-1*7=6. Subtract (3) from (2) and -1*13+2*7=1. x=-1 and y=-2. If you wanted positive numbers, add 7*13 - 13*7=0 giving 6*13 - 11*7 =1. Basically Euclid’s algorithm but keeping track of some equation at the same time.

Comment: Note: in my prior comment, $\, y\equiv 11\pmod{\!13}\,$ means $\, y = 11+ 13j\,$ for some integer $\,j,\,$ which is precisely what you seek.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of the ideas presented in @aqualubix's comment, modular arithmetic may be used to solve this Diophantine equation (without brute force). Rearranging the equation, we have
$$13x=7y+1,$$
and setting $a=13x=7y+1$, we have the system of congruences
$$\begin{cases}
a &\equiv 0 \pmod{13},\\
a &\equiv 1 \pmod{7}.
\end{cases}$$
Since $13$ and $7$ are coprime, we may use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to solve this system and ensure a unique expression for $a$ in $\mathbb{Z}/91\mathbb{Z}$. We see that
$$a=7k+1$$
for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, and plugging this into our first congruence, we obtain
$$7k+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{13} \iff k \equiv 11 \pmod{13}.$$
Hence, we have that
$$k=13j+11$$
for some $j \in \mathbb{Z}$, and we obtain
$$a=7(13j+11)+1 = 91j+78, \ \ j \in \mathbb{Z}.$$
However,
$$91j+78=a=13x \implies x=7j+6,$$
and likewise, plugging in our formula for $a$ gives a general form for $y$ in terms of $j \in \mathbb{Z}$, which turns out to be your
$$y=13j+11$$
in question.

Comment: I have tried understanding this again and again. But where I seem to lose you is how do you jump from k= 11 to k = 13j + 11

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs (& PSQs), cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).